# Use service inside Reducer in RXJS 6

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, reducers, ngrx-effects

In the Effect of the Authentication I'm handling the servers error:

```
catchError((err, caught) => {
   let toasterPayload = {
       title: 'Error',
       message: err,
       conf: {}
    }

    return [
       {
           type: CoreActions.SHOW_ERROR_TOASTR,
           payload: toasterPayload
       },
       caught
    ];
```

The target is to let the stream of Observable flow, and then dispatch an action that show the toaster. To **not** repeat the string `this.toastrService.error(..,..)` in witch catchError of all effects of my application, I wrote a generic and common action (**SHOW_ERROR_TOASTR**):

```
...other cases...
case (CoreActions.SHOW_ERROR_TOASTR):
    toastrService.error(action.payload.title, action.payload.message, action.payload.config);
    return state;
```

At the top of the reducer file I imported the Toastr service:

```
import * as toastrService from 'ngx-toastr';
```

but it output the following error:

> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Users/myPc/projects/test/node_modules/ngx-toastr/ngx-toastr"'.

How can I inject properly (and use it) a service inside a reducer? Is this a good practice to centralize the code (to not repeat the toaster in all catchErrors)?

Comment: shouldn't it be `import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';`

Comment: I already tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: same error or new ones?

Comment: Importing: import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr'; and writing: this.ToastrService.error(..) it compiles correctly but when the action is dispatched I have this error in console of the browser: Cannot read property 'ToastrService' of undefined. 

Writing just ToastrService.error(..) so without the 'this', I have this compilation error: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'typeof ToastrService'

Comment: show the constructor

Comment: It hasn't a constructor, it is a Reducer so a pure function

Comment: if you are using a angular service you have to inject to your reducer through constructor

Comment: How can I provide a constructor even if it is not expected in the reducer?

Comment: you have to change you logic i guess

Comment: Is it possible, and relatively easy, to just `new` up the toaster service in the reducer where you need it? That way, you avoid dealing with injection. Not ideal, but an acceptable work around considering you may never get injection to work in this situation.